# Create shape as if molded by enclosing object

Tags: modeling

I have this jar:

[image]

Now I'd like to create a separate object, with a shape that perfectly fits the inside of this jar. As if the jar is a mold for the new object. Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Select the inner faces of the jar, duplicate, fill the top and bottom?

Comment: @moonboots that's what I did, took me about 2 minutes though, so was wondering if there was a quicker way

Comment: You're too impatient! :^))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Select the inner face ring with <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>LMB</kbd> then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>+</kbd> to select the adjacent faces, duplicate with <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>, separate if necessary (<kbd>P</kbd>), fill the top and bottom faces:

[image]

Comment: thanks, worked but with lmb instead of rmb

Comment: OK, thanks, I've corrected ;)